# readUTF works once, then throws EOFException

Tags: java, exception, utf-8, randomaccessfile

I'm writing to a `RandomAccessFile` like that: (in a LinkedList's subclass)

```
file.setLength(0);
for (Person person : this)
    file.writeUTF(person.getBlob());
```

`Person.getBlob()` returns a string of constant length, containing only basic alphanumeric characters, spaces and CRs (only one-byte characters). At this place the file contains exactly 100 records. (confirmed with a hex editor)

Then I try to read that file:

```
int counter = 0;

while (true) {
    try {
        add(Person.fromBlob(file.readUTF()));
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.println(counter + " records read from file.");
        break;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new DBException(exception);
    }

    counter++;
}
```

I always end up with one record read correctly and an `EOFException`. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Did you rewind the file?

Comment: Program creates that file if it doesn't exist and exits, then reads it when started again. So yes, the file is being read from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. That class had a custom `add()` method that rewrote the file everytime something was added. At the beginning of the loop there were 100 entries, but after it executed once only one entry was left. There was also some extra code that had always added those missing 99 entries.

Replacing `add()` with `super.add()` solved the problem.